# Compare 2 text files and output a difference

Tags: python, batch-file, compare, difference

I have two text files:

First text file:

```
email1@domain.com:password
email2@domain.com:password
email3@domain.com:password
email4@domain.com:password
email5@domain.com:password
```

2nd text file:

```
email3@domain.com:password
email5@domain.com:password
```

How can I output the differences between them regardless of the line number? I want to output a third file:

third text file:

```
email1@domain.com:password
email2@domain.com:password
email4@domain.com:password
```

Comment: do you want to only match the username or both username and password? Your example is ambiguous

Comment: Both, could you post an example with Username only?

Comment: Also, you showed here those that are missing in file2, what if there is a line in file2 absent from file1?

Comment: Ok, let me explain a bit better. The first file contains all original emails and passwords. The 2nd file contains some of it (from the first file), so I want to output a difference into a third text file to see which lines are missing from the first file.

Comment: In a [tag:batch-file] use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html): `findstr /V /I /X /L /G:"2nd.txt" "1st.txt" > "3rd.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the username and password are separated by colon then you could do this:

```
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
usernames = [set(), set()]
for i, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(file) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            usernames[i].add(line.split(':')[0])
for d in usernames[0] - usernames[1]:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file1Lines = open("file1.txt", "r").readlines()
file2Lines = open("file2.txt", "r").readlines()
file1Lines.close()
file2Lines.close()
file3LinesOutput = []
for line in file1Lines:
    if line not in file2Lines:
        file3LinesOutput.append(line)
file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")
file3.writelines(file3LinesOutput)
filr3.close()
```

This should do what you asked for. It will add to a third file every line that's in the first file but not in the second one

Answer (score 0):

You can split this into a list.

Let's assume that the first text is stored in the variable **first_text**, the second one, **second_text**.

As the only thing that differenciates one from another is the break line, you could split them with:

```py
first_list = first_text.split('\n')
second_list = second_text.split('\n')
```

So, now you have all your e-mails separated in lists. From here you can just compare both lists and store in **output_text**.

```py
output_list = first_list
for email_first in first_list:
    for email_second in second_list:
        if (email_first == email_second):
            output_list.remove(email_first)
```

Note that this is for your specific example, and doesn't cover properly a case in which the second list is bigger than the first one.